# Longblob alternative in Hibernate + HSQLDB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hsqldb

I have a column in a MySQL database defined as LONGBLOB. This is the java code used on its mapping:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
@Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
private Point latlng;
```

I want now to share this definition in an HSQLDB (for in-memory testing), but unfortunately HSQLDB doesn't have the LONGBLOB type.

I know about the HSQLDB alternatives such as LONGVARBINARY, but how I can instruct Hibernate to use LONGBLOB on MySQL and LONGVARBINARY on HSQLDB?

(I can't replace the @Column with @Lob; I tried that and Hibernate uses by default a "geometry" type instead of "longblob". Changing the current MySQL mapping is not an option.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML mappings with `orm.xml` overwrites annotated mappings.

So, you could include XML mapping file for this entity in `/src/test/resources/` and define the proper datatype for this column.